# Yahoo finance in angular 4

Tags: angular, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

Im trying to fetch historical prices for stocks from yahoo finance. 
I've created this function:

```
  getHistorical(ticker: string, startDate: Date, endDate: Date): Promise<string> {

//Dates to string    
let startString = this.datePipe.transform(startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
let endString = this.datePipe.transform(endDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

//Build request
let url = 'http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=04&b=01&c=2017&d=04&e=06&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv';
let cors = 'https://crossorigin.me/'
this.http.get(cors+url)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => console.log(response))
           .catch(error => console.log(error));

return Promise.resolve(ticker + " " + startString + " " + endString);
```

}

I get a response but it seems to be empty:

```
    true
status
:
200
statusText
:
"OK"
type
:
2
url
:
"https://crossorigin.me/http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=04&b=01&c=2017&d=04&e=06&f=2017&g=d&ignore=.csv"
_body
:
"Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
2017-05-05,146.759995,148.979996,146.759995,148.960007,26787400,148.960007
2017-05-04,146.520004,147.139999,145.809998,146.529999,23309300,146.529999
2017-05-03,145.589996,147.490005,144.270004,147.059998,45404200,147.059998
2017-05-02,147.539993,148.089996,146.839996,147.509995,40290100,147.509995
2017-05-01,145.100006,147.199997,144.960007,146.580002,33424500,146.580002"
```

It seems to be working now but how can I extract the data from the body?

Br

Comment: It's not Angular's problem though. Check API and your input. Do some manual requests first to ensure it works.

Comment: Ive updated the question. I get result but in the body which I cant uses. :S

Comment: You can use response._body and parse it.